# Moving bars in bar graph

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

How do you make the bars on the right appear next to the bars on the left, so it doesn't look so silly?

[image]

LateX code for figure:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}

\begin{document}
    % Data
    %----------------------------------------
    \pgfplotstableread[row sep=\\,col sep=&]{
        descr & DCPT & RPT            \\
        Description1     & 0.664  & 0.583 \\
        Description2     & 0.471  & 0.10  \\
        }\mydata

    % Plot
    %----------------------------------------
    \begin{figure}[!htb]
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
                ybar = 7pt,
                symbolic x coords={Description1, Description2},
                xticklabel style={rotate=45},
                xtick=data,
                nodes near coords,
                nodes near coords align={vertical},
                ymin=0, ymax=0.8,
            ]
            \addplot table[x=descr,y=DCPT]{\mydata};
            \addplot table[x=descr,y=RPT]{\mydata};
            \legend{Data1, Data2}
        \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \caption{Caption.}
        \label{fig:statistics}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you please make your code compilable? Please also clarify: Where should the legend be placed?

Comment: My appologies, the code is now compilable. The legend is not really important as long as it's visible. I just want the bars to be next to each other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can enlarge the limits of the x axis by a factor with the `enlarge x limits` key.
[image: bar-plot]

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}

\begin{document}
    % Data
    %----------------------------------------
    \pgfplotstableread[row sep=\\,col sep=&]{
        descr & DCPT & RPT            \\
        Description1     & 0.664  & 0.583 \\
        Description2     & 0.471  & 0.10  \\
        }\mydata

    % Plot
    %----------------------------------------
    \begin{figure}[!htb]
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
                ybar = 7pt,
                symbolic x coords={Description1, Description2},
                xticklabel style={rotate=45},
                xtick=data,
                enlarge x limits = 0.5,
                nodes near coords,
                nodes near coords align={vertical},
                ymin=0, ymax=0.8,
            ]
            \addplot table[x=descr,y=DCPT]{\mydata};
            \addplot table[x=descr,y=RPT]{\mydata};
            \legend{Data1, Data2}
        \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \caption{Caption.}
        \label{fig:statistics}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```